# Error with IOWebSocketChannel and web socket asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, sockets, http, flutter

I wanted to ask you if anyone has had problems connecting an asp.net web socket with IOWebSocketChannel is Flutter. If I use wss: //echo.websocket.org it works perfect. This is my code:

WebSocketChannel channel;

```
void initState()
{
  super.initState();

  try
  {

     channel= IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://wsocket.pruebas.com?enterpriseId=100A4E4C-F771-1002-9C60-C000D4518D9F');
 
    channel.stream.listen(onSocketData,onError: onSocketData,onDone: onSocketDone);


  }
  catch(e)
  {
    print("initState -> Error -> " + e.toString());
  }

}

onSocketData(event)
{
  print('Socket Recibido - ' + event);
}

onSocketDone()
{
  print('Socket Cerrado');
}

onSocketError(err)
{
  print('Socket Error RunTime Type - ' + err.runtimeType.toString());
  WebSocketChannelException ex = err;
  print('Socket Error  - ' + ex.message);
}


void sendData(String strDato)
{
     print("sendData - " + strDato);

     channel.sink.add(strDato);

}
```

In onSocketData (event) I get the error:

**Connection to 'http://wsocket.pruebas.com?enterpriseId=100A4E4C-F771-1002-9C60-C000D4518D9F#' was not upgraded to websocket**

Which may be? I have tried with ip, with ports and it gives the same error, and this web socket is working without problems on a web page that i have.

Comment: I still can't do it, maybe there is another component?

Comment: Solved, use httpClient, the problem is the headers, dart converts them all to lowercase. Thanks for the help

Comment: May I ask how you got this to work? You said you used httpClient, but where did you use this, and how?